# Theme designer ?

Tags: feature-request, 7-essential, appearance

Since we're close to the 90 day mark (I would have said 'getting out of beta', but that's not the case any more) I continue to wonder about the magical incantations needed to set us FREE ! In particular, I wonder when we'll be graced by a visit from [Jin the theme design deity](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/users/33/jin), who's done a bang up job for [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) and [tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) already (and others too, but these are the most relevant to us).

SE mods ? Any feedback on this ?

Update: Never mind, the entire sequence of events [is detailed here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/conversation/chat-cast-009-open-talk). In brief, we have to wait our turn, and make sure we have enough excellent/okay ratings.

Comment: The "detailed here" links appears broken.

Comment: mm. maybe it's for mods only. I'll summarize the important content in an answer.

Answer (score 11):

See: [Design Ideas for TCS Site](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/701/design-ideas-for-tcs-site)

Answer (score 6):

The summary, from this week's moderator chat-cast, is this:

> - Any site past 90 days goes into a pool of sites to graduate.
> - Jin is able to design about 1 to 1-1/2 sites per week so we have to
>     come up with an order to launch those
>     sites...
> - Based on this blog post [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/), the sites with
>     enough 2000 and 3000-rep users go
>     first.
> - The order after that is determined by the [Area 51 statistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8766/theoretical-computer-science): The
>     most Excellent, Okay, and Worrying, in
>     that order.

I was looking over the sites currently in beta, and once we cross the 'active user' boundary into excellent, which should happen once we get three more 200+ rep users, we should be in decent shape to move on.

**Update**: we are now upto 4 excellents. I'm thinking that once we cross the 90 day mark, we might be on the way.