# New Design Launched

Tags: design

Hi all,

The new design just went live, congratulations on the official launch and thank you for your [design input](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/701/design-ideas-for-tcs-site)!

If you see any CSS/Styling issues, please start a new question for the bug report, and tag it with "Design" and "Bug." It will be a lot easier for me to track new questions than reading the comments replied to this thread. A note for IE6/IE7, while we try to make sure the site is functional for people using older browsers, we don't support them to the point of pixel perfectness.

I typically fix CSS/usability issues asap. As for more subjective styling requests, I tend to let the new design simmer a bit. After having used the Beta Sketchy theme for a few months, it will take a bit of time to get used to the new design.

The favicons may be cached by your browsers, to see the new ones, load the following URL in your browser's address bar and hard refresh.

http://sstatic.net/cstheory/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/cstheorymeta/img/favicon.ico

P.S. I'll be hanging out in the [TCS Chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47) this week on and off. Feel free to send me feedback there too(although I still prefer bug reports to be posted here on Meta).

Comment: Great work guys!  Looks awesome!

Comment: Thanks, Jin!  Very professionally done.

Comment: Thanks Jin, you are really fast. :)

Comment: The most recent rollout has no announcement on Meta, so I will post a comment on this ancient announcement. The buttons are almost invisible, there's a question on Meta here: https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3016/broken-button-design

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps I am alone in this, but the color scheme of both meta and parent seem a bit faded out.  I would prefer a blue with more hue in the "title tape" and darker question titles in both parent and meta.

Comment: I agree.  I was going to make the same comment.

Comment: I'd second the request for darker titles and more hue

Comment: I'd third it ;)

Comment: Yes, I would also prefer a little bit sharper contrast and bolder or larger fonts.

Comment: 5th. .  .    .     .      .       .        .         .          !

Comment: As for the "title tape", it really it not too readable. Should it be? If so, more contrast between letters and tape is in order.

Comment: @Aaron I'll adjust the contrast in the question title.

Comment: Thank you Jin.  I can read it much better now.  I also opened the page in a computer running an older browser and it looks really good there, too, whereas the beta layout did not.

Answer (score 5):

Courier in buttons like "Add Comment" and "Post Your Answer" clashes with the other (much nicer) fonts.  Holdover from design #1?

Comment: I think that the choice of the font is intentional; these buttons look like key top.  I do not see any problem with it.  The typewriter font is also used in the website name.

Answer (score 5):

The overall design looks nice, but I'm finding the new fonts much harder to read than the fonts that were used in the beta version.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?  Because I was before, and now I'm not.  I think it was a background-slash-text-contrast issue, as opposed to the fonts that were chosen.

Answer (score 4):

I would love to see customized badge symbols.

My first idea has been to give them the appearance of coins minted with well-known complexity classes.

I am sure others have better ideas than that.

Comment: I am afraid that it is probably too late to introduce new design elements.  In addition, I cannot imagine how to fit more than one letter in the tiny badge icon.

Comment: We could have used classes with only 1 letter. For example the classes, L, P and E, for bronze, silver and gold.

Comment: @Robin: In that case, it is difficult to get that those letters refer to the complexity classes.  I do not think that it is a welcoming design for those who do not understand what they mean.

Comment: We certainly need some insider jokes on a self-proclaimed elitist site.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to note that, IMHO, the previous design was better. I think the title bar for Theoretical Computer Science covering the whole width of the screen is distracting. If one looks at websites like stackoverflow and mathoverflow, the logo covers only a very small part of the screen.

Comment: The title tape is too wide for my taste, too. Any experiences on small screens?

Comment: I like the design overall but definitely find myself getting visually distracted by the bright, wide tape at the top even when I'm focusing on items lower on the screen. How about this: Decrease the intensity of the tape, increase the intensity and contrast of the body fonts. Most importantly, add a fading transparency gradient as the tape approaches the left and right edge. Aside from being less visually dominating, it also has the side benefit of emphasizing the doubly-infinite nature of Turing tapes.

Comment: +1 for fading effect at the ends of the TM tape.

Comment: I tried it on my phone (Nexus One), in small screens the only part of the tape shown is "Theoretical Computer Science", so there does not seem to be problem with small screens.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing really bothering me is the mix between serif and sans-serif fonts.  Maybe it is just my browser, but I see the article titles with a serif, and this breaks the continuity of the page.
Glad to see some personality for this website, though !

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor issue, the font color of the tags [featured] and [faq] in meta seems to collide with the background color. Maybe using white like [status-completed], or say yellow if we want to emphasize the difference.

Comment: I think that the styles for [featured], [faq] and [status-completed] are the same (all of them are moderator tags).

Comment: the fix will be in the next deployment

Answer (score 1):

I propose giving user signatures (i.e. time, username, avatar, reputation, badge count) less opacity than text since focus should be on questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

At least on my browser (Chrome) the vote count appears vertically off-center between the up and down voting buttons. This is more pronounced with some numerals than others, so I guess it's possible the CSS positioning is correct but the numeral font has inconsistent x-height.

Comment: same issue reported here: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/720/two-minor-issues-with-the-look-of-vote-counts-and-vote-icons

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I can't see a thing and need to squint to see it.  meta is a bit better than the standard site.  But it is really rough on the eyes

Comment: I'm afraid to ask, and I don't mean to be rude at all. It might be an accessibility problem. Are you stating that the site theme is hard to see even for normal eyes, or you mean it's problematic for those who have an eye condition? (In the latter case, please be more specific.)

Comment: @Sadeq I have normal eyes and just the lightness of the colors, the brightest of the white and the lack of definition in the font(which may be my system on this site) just makes it very hard for me to see.  I very well may be the only one.  Just the meta cstheory site is far easier for me to see.

Comment: @Recursion: Sure, I see. So, since I see them well, there might be a problem with your monitor settings. In the chat rooms, I saw that Jin offered to tune it using tests in http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/. Could you please take a look at it and report the results? **PS:** You can also take screenshots and upload them, so that we can see what's going on on your display (not sure it works, but it doesn't hurt either).

Comment: Do you still have this problem (after a Shift-reload to make sure)?  I am asking this because Jin changed the color of the question titles to a darker one on Thursday night http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/211567#211567, so the problem may have gone now.

Comment: @Sadeq Bookmarked, I will have to do this later tonight.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi:  I don't really remember, but it seems similar, but maybe slightly darker.  It may not be as bright.  Thank you.