# Font size of "Answers" in personal pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

First of all we are happy to see that [TCS Stack Exchange is launched](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/712/new-design-launched)!! And again many thanks to Jin for making such a high-quality design, it is awesome!!

I found out that the font size of the titles in the "Answers" part of personal pages is a little bit small.

[image: Answer_font_pic]

I wonder if this only happen to me? (Maybe I have selected a tiny-size web font)
This size is good for tags and badges, however it seems that the up-voted counts are even larger than the titles. Maybe with a little bit larger font (but not too much!) will make one easy to read and the LaTeX code inside will look better.

Thank you for all your hard work!!

Comment: I have the same problem. The font for answers seems much smaller than the one for questions.

Comment: i'm fixing this now. thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this. It will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Thank you very much!!