# Broken button design

Tags: bug, design

The colour scheme for buttons on the main site seems to have changed recently:

[image]

It makes them nearly unreadable, and they have a disabled look.

Comment: See also https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3870/buttons-white-on-light-grey-look-like-they-are-inactive